# How to check htmlElement object exists in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have htmlElement object and I need check it on exists in DOM:
It doesn't exist by selector.

```
$(htmlElement).length // 1 
$(htmlElement)[0].className // k-button k-state-hover 
$(htmlElement)[0].nodeName // LI 
$("li.k-button.k-state-hover").length // 0
```

Comment: What is your issue here?

Comment: What is `htmlElement`, then? @PatsyIssa This isn't a duplicate of that question, the OP isn't asking for a 'more elegant way' to check for an element.

Comment: @PatsyIssa not exactly a duplicate if `htmlElement` is a dom element reference

Comment: @ArunPJohny But if `htmlElement` is a DOM node, what's wrong with: `if($(htmlElement).length)` ? EDIT: sorry, i see what you mean by 'not exactly a duplicate' even still hard for me to figure out what is OP's issue here, even the question

Comment: @A.Wolff I think if it is a dom node then jQuery will not do a dom look up.... try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fFq48/3/ - the newly created dom element also returned true

Comment: @ArunPJohny Oh ya, of course! My bad! Could be what OP is looking for, not sure http://jsfiddle.net/fFq48/4/

Comment: I think OP is asking how to check whether `htmlElement` is attached to the DOM or not.

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks! I forgot about body =( But phuzi ask right to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether the DOM contains `htmlElement` with

```
if ($.contains(document, $(htmlElement)){
    // htmlElement is attached to the DOM
}
```

Comment: Nice one indeed! Really readable!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(htmlElement.length > 0) {
    //Do what you need
}
```

or

```
if($('tag').length > 0) {
    //YOUR CODE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to give proper condition you always need to check length of object

i.e if($("li.k-button.k-state-hover").length)

Answer (score 0):

**Try with javascript:**

```
var ele =  document.getElementById('yourId');

 or

var ele = document.getElementByTagName('tag name');

if (typeof(ele) != 'undefined' && ele != null)
{
  // exists.
}
```